# Unix Bash scripts empty file condtions

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a bash script with the following lines

```
for file in $diff_file_list
    do

        # replace any ? with $current_date and replace any % with $file
        formatted_output_filename=$(echo $output_filename | sed "s|?|$current_date|g" | sed "s|%|_$file|g")
        $pig_bin_dir/pig -param preceding=$hdfs_hadoop_pre_dir/$file -param current=$hdfs_hadoop_cur_dir/$file -param output_added=$hdfs_hadoop_delta_dir/${file}_added -param output_removed=$hdfs_hadoop_delta_dir/${file}_removed -param delimiter=$delimiter diff.pig
        [ $? -ne 0 ] && die "diff of data between $previous_date and $current_date using pig failed. exiting `basename $0` script"
        $hadoop_bin_dir/hadoop dfs -cat $hdfs_hadoop_delta_dir/${file}_added/* | gzip > $file_output_dir/${formatted_output_filename}_added.gz
        $hadoop_bin_dir/hadoop dfs -cat $hdfs_hadoop_delta_dir/${file}_removed/* | gzip > $file_output_dir/${formatted_output_filename}_removed.gz
        [ $? -ne 0 ] && die "there was a problem gzipping ${formatted_output_filename}. exiting `basename $0` script"
        [ $post_diff_script ] && ./$post_diff_script $source $previous_date $current_date

    done
```

I only want it to create the _removed.gz and _added.gz files when the file is not empty. 
I've tried to do this below but there is something wrong with my script?

```
    for file in $diff_file_list
    do

        # replace any ? with $current_date and replace any % with $file
        formatted_output_filename=$(echo $output_filename | sed "s|?|$current_date|g" | sed "s|%|_$file|g")
        $pig_bin_dir/pig -param preceding=$hdfs_hadoop_pre_dir/$file -param current=$hdfs_hadoop_cur_dir/$file -param output_added=$hdfs_hadoop_delta_dir/${file}_added -param output_removed=$hdfs_hadoop_delta_dir/${file}_removed -param delimiter=$delimiter diff.pig
        [ $? -ne 0 ] && die "diff of data between $previous_date and $current_date using pig failed. exiting `basename $0` script"
        if [[ -s $hdfs_hadoop_delta_dir/${file}_added/* ]] ; then
        echo "$hdfs_hadoop_delta_dir/${file}_added/* has data."
        $hadoop_bin_dir/hadoop dfs -cat $hdfs_hadoop_delta_dir/${file}_added/* | gzip > $file_output_dir/${formatted_output_filename}_added.gz
        $hadoop_bin_dir/hadoop dfs -cat $hdfs_hadoop_delta_dir/${file}_removed/* | gzip > $file_output_dir/${formatted_output_filename}_removed.gz
        else
        echo "$hdfs_hadoop_delta_dir/${file}_added/*is empty."
        fi ;
        [ $? -ne 0 ] && die "there was a problem gzipping ${formatted_output_filename}. exiting `basename $0` script"
        [ $post_diff_script ] && ./$post_diff_script $source $previous_date $current_date

    done
```

Comment: yeah your scripts are shouting at me.

Comment: A couple of notes. First, although `[ x ] && y` works, it's more readable to write it as `if [x]; then y; fi`. Also, try breaking very long lines in multiple lines. It would also help to align some stuff, for example the many `-param` options send to `pig` (after you break it in multiple lines). Finally, when you say "there is something wrong", you should be more specific. What exactly happens?

Comment: You can put a newline after any `|` symbol, and you can use line continuations (\\) before any newline.  Doing so will render the script much more readable.

Comment: the if [[ -s <dir>/* ]] won't work. I can think of workarounds but their may be a elegant solution out there...

Comment: re-edited to make this less shouty

Comment: Do you want to check if a *file* is empty, or a *directory*?

Comment: I want to check if a file is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if [[ -s file ]]
then
    do_file_creation
fi
```

or

```
for f in dir/*
do
    if [[ -s $f ]]
    then
        do_file_creation
    fi
done
```

Use lower case or mixed case variable names.

Use `if` instead of `[[ ]] &&`

Use indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a solution that does not add a loop. It is not as clean, though:

```
if [[ -s `ls -S $hdfs_hadoop_delta_dir/${file}_added/* 2>/dev/null | head -1` ]] ; then
```

`ls -S` sorts files by file size, and `head -1` takes the largest one, which is then tested to be non-zero by `if [[ -s`.

Unfortunately one has to handle the case where there are no files. I used `2>/dev/null`. Anyone has a better idea?

Comment: [BashFAQ/003](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) is applicable to  "largest" as well as "newest/oldest".